# android mupdf for MIPS and x86 arch

Tags: android, mupdf

im currently using `MuPDF` in my android application, when i built it from source (based on ReadMe.txt) it's only generate `.so` file for `armeabi` and `armeabi-v7a` but not `x86` and `MIPS`, when i run the app on arm arch devices (Samsung Galaxy Tab 7), it looks good. But not in `mips` arch. my question is how i can generate `x86` and `MIPS` shared object file? if any other solution, i will appreciate it...

PS: i'm using `android ndk r8d`, i tried to change with `android-ndk-r6b` but i got same problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look in android/jni/Application.mk within the mupdf source you will see a line:

```
APP_ABI = armeabi armeabi-v7a
```

You can make this:

```
APP_ABI = armeabi armeabi-v7a x86 mips
```

or even:

```
APP_ABI = all
```

to enable the other architectures.

This will cause problems currently as android/jni/Core.mk and android/jni/Core2.mk files define -DARCH_ARM and -DARCH_THUMB (as at the time they were written, Android only supported ARM processors). This needs a bit of magic with the preprocessor:

```
ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH),arm)
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DARCH_ARM -DARCH_THUMB -DARCH_ARM_CAN_LOAD_UNALIGNED
ifdef NDK_PROFILER
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -pg -DNDK_PROFILER -O2
endif
endif
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DAA_BITS=8
```

I will get fixes put in for these - watch our git repo over the next couple of days.
EDIT: Fix is now committed.

Comment: yes i get latest source, but i get error :: C:/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/x86-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.6/../../../../i686-linux-android/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/x86/objs/mupdf/mupdf.o: in function Java_com_artifex_mupdfdemo_MuPDFCore_openFile:jni/mupdf.c:296: error: undefined reference to 'sigsetjmp'. how i do fix that?

Comment: having same issue, did you find a fix?

Comment: The lack of sigsetjmp is a bug in that particular NDK release. Use r8e and you'll be fine, I think.