# Build MuPDF for all architectures. (android ndk)

Tags: android, pdf, architecture, android-ndk

I want to build MuPDF pdf viewer for android.I followed the instructions from their [website]

It basically tells me to do this:

> Prepare the source
>
> Check out a copy of the mupdf source from git:
>
> ~/src $ git clone git://git.ghostscript.com/mupdf.git Check out the
>   third party library submodules:
>
> ~/src/mupdf $ git submodule update --init Populate the generated
>   directory with the necessary files:
>
> ~/src/mupdf $ make generate Build and debug
>
> Change into the platform/android directory and edit the local
>   properties configuration file.
>
> ~/src/mupdf $ cd platform/android ~/src/mupdf/platform/android $ cp
>   local.properties.sample local.properties ~/src/mupdf/platform/android
>   $ nano local.properties Build the native code libraries:
>
> ~/src/mupdf/platform/android $ ndk-build

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15110168/2670775)

*Note here that I have almost no idea about native code in android. So, there might be the possibility of me missing some simple step.* I followed the above steps exactly except the nano part(about editing the local.properties file).

After following the steps, I imported the project into eclipse. The problem is, I only see ONE folder under libs (named armeabi-v7a). I want to build MUPDF for other architectures as well(armeabi, mips,x86) and be able to run the app across all these architectures.

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15110168/2670775), but I cant find any line like **APP_ABI**. So my question is how do I build for other architectures?

Comment: In "nano part" you should create local.properties file and set path to your sdk. After that try to repeat next steps

Comment: possible duplicate of [android mupdf for MIPS and x86 arch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15103022/android-mupdf-for-mips-and-x86-arch)